# Why are absolute reads from a ByteBuffer not considered thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, nio, bytebuffer

My use case requires a directly allocated [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) that is written to once and thereafter read by many concurrent threads. All reads are absolute and so I'm never concerned with the buffer's state (position, limit, mark).

[This article](http://www.kdgregory.com/?page=java.byteBuffer) on byte buffers by Keith Gregory warns that even absolute reads are not considered thread-safe:

> `ByteBuffer` thread safety is covered in the [`Buffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html) JavaDoc; the short version is that buffers are not thread-safe. Clearly, you can't use relative positioning from multiple threads without a race condition, **but even absolute positioning is not guaranteed (regardless of what you might think after looking at the implementation classes)**.

(emphasis mine)

Because of this warning, I'm preceding every read from the byte buffer with a call to [`duplicate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#duplicate--). This is easy enough, but the extra object allocation on every single read has me curious why it's actually necessary.

Despite Keith's wizardly disclaimer, I did look at OpenJDK's [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/nio/DirectByteBuffer.java#DirectByteBuffer.get%28int%29) of an absolute read from a direct byte buffer:

```
public byte get(int i) {
    return ((unsafe.getByte(ix(checkIndex(i)))));
}
```

You can see that it simply delegates to [`Unsafe.getByte(long)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/misc/Unsafe.java#Unsafe.getByte%28long%29), which "fetches a value from a given memory address".

I understand that different implementations could exist, but what reasonably couldn't be thread-safe about this operation? Does the `Buffer` contract simply decline to guarantee thread-safety for absolute reads in order to avoid the confusion of a partially thread-safe class? Or if the warning is justified for concurrent writes, what about my situation, in which the byte buffer is unmodified after creation? Also, would anything change when using a [`MappedByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html) instead?

Related:

- [What is the use of ByteBuffer in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841340/what-is-the-use-of-bytebuffer-in-java)
- [The Java ByteBuffer – a crash course](http://worldmodscode.wordpress.com/2012/12/14/the-java-bytebuffer-a-crash-course/)
- [Atomic read then write of part of a ByteBuffer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328459/atomic-read-then-write-of-part-of-a-bytebuffer-in-java)
- [Options to make Java's ByteBuffer thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153583/options-to-make-javas-bytebuffer-thread-safe)

Comment: Hmm. A lot of unsubstantiated opinion there. For example "I don't think this takes the Java memory model into account". The implementation *must* (a) obey the specification stated in the Javadoc and (b) take the Java memory model into account when doing so.

Comment: @EJP The Java Memory Model remark seems to refer to direct buffers, which live outside the Java heap. They're basically memory-mapped IO operations, and IO operations on files (or anything outside the Java heap/stack/etc.) don't have to adhere to the Java Memory model

Comment: Even when ignoring visibility issues you'll get without proper synchronization, the `get` method is not atomic. It accesses the shared data array and performs an index check which involves reading the shared state `limit`.

Comment: *Nothing* is thread safe unless some mechanism has made it thread safe.

Comment: @PaulBellora - I added that line in response to a colleague who was sharing a buffer between threads. And my answer to you is the same as to him: yes, it certainly looks threadsafe to me, but I don't want to change a lot of code if we ever use a JVM where it isn't threadsafe. I believe the thread-local copy (shown lower in that article) is the best approach. I certainly *wouldn't* duplicate on every use.

Comment: @EJP - As I read [JLS 17.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.1), the Java memory model applies *only* to on-heap memory accessed via Java's normal mechanisms (`getfield` *et al*). Any given buffer may or may not be backed by on-heap storage, and any given JVM may or may not take off-heap storage into account when erecting memory barriers. It's highly likely that X86 JVMs would use `MFENCE` for synchronized`, and my understanding of that operation is that it's a global barrier, but I'm not willing to bet on that implementation.

Comment: @kdgregory Thanks for your comments. Would you be able to post an answer addressing my questions? I'm particularly interested in why using `duplicate` isn't advisable, keeping in mind my buffer is effectively read-only after initialization.

Comment: @PaulBellora Going by the documentation of ByteBuffer only (i.e. not the implementation), invoking `duplicate` does not provide you with any safety guarantee unless you invoked `duplicate` with proper synchronization (e.g. inside a lock). The thread safety disclaimer in javadoc of Buffer did not provide any carve out for `duplicate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are absolute reads from a ByteBuffer not considered thread-safe?

Given the nature of the direct memory buffer (think mmap and other hardware backed files) that can be underneath the `ByteBuffer`, any external updates are *guaranteed* to not be properly synchronized -- not good.  In addition, the fact that `slice()` and `duplicate()` are designed to use the same buffer means that although *your* `ByteBuffer` may be used in a thread-safe manner, there may be no guarantee that the "source" buffer is.  These complexities may be the reason why blanket not-for-threads warnings are used.

> Because of this warning, I'm preceding every read from the byte buffer with a call to duplicate.

As you mention, different JDKs and/or Java versions may have different implementations but I agree that I don't see any problem with you using the buffer unsynchronized as long as you are careful.

1. The memory backing the `ByteBuffer` must not being modified by any external entitiy.
2. You must instantiate the `ByteBuffer` and make any mutating method calls (i.e.e `put(...)` etc.) *before* the threads are created or the field holding the buffer needs to be `volatile`.
3. Your buffer probably should not be a slice, duplicate, or otherwise sharing bytes with any other buffer.
4. Only `get(...)` non-mutating methods are used by the threads.  This means that (like you mention) you can't depend on the value of the `offset` field.  But also be careful of the `array()` method that returns the actual array buffer and not a copy.  Any mutating of the returned array will not be thread-safe.

Keith's article hints at some of this:

> That said, you still have the issue of creating buffers: you need to synchronize access to the slice() or duplicate() call. One way to do this is to create all of your buffers before spawning threads. However, that may be inconvenient, especially if your buffer is internal to another class. An alternative is to use ThreadLocal...

Like all threaded issues, the devil is in the details here and I admit that I don't have much experience with the `Unsafe.getByte(...)` type methods directly aside from `ByteBuffer.wrap(...)`.

> Also, would anything change when using a MappedByteBuffer instead?

Use of `MappedByteBuffer` is what makes the #1 above of paramount importance.  Also, again, any calls to `load()` must happen in a thread safe way (see #2).

If there is any question, one thing to consider is to use `ByteBuffer.wrap(...)` and not use the loading mechanism and the direct memory stuff.  Certainly you should run some performance tests to see what the impact is because you may find that making this appropriately synchronized (in a memory sense) may be more expensive than doing the load "by hand".  Be careful about premature optimizations.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! To clarify, what's the meaning of "ENOGOOD"? I searched but couldn't find an explanation

Comment: Sorry, nerd talk.  ENOGOOD is an old unix errno meaning invalid errno value.  I use it to mean not good.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Oh haha #til and thank you for the well thought out answer!

Answer (score -1):

For one the Buffer documentation states that access to the buffer should be synchronized. It does no say that it must not be used by different threads. So I think a `duplicate` is not required.

That you can not think of a reasonable non-threadsafe implementation of some method or other is more a limit of your imagination than proof that caution is not necessary. Especially considering that you did not look at the Oracle Java code, when it was Oracle stating that the implementation is not threadsafe.

My advise: do some reasonable synchronization when accessing the buffer. Even if there never will be a non-threadsafe implementation it will not cost you much.

Comment: I preferred using `duplicate` over synchronization to avoid contention. Unfortunately your middle paragraph is more of a comment than an answer - my lack of proof and limited imagination are why I asked the question.

Comment: @Paul well there's the obvious case of an implementation reading/writing a byte at a time which would lead to torn reads/writes.

Comment: @Paul `duplicate` itself is not thread-safe, so you might not use it from different threads without proper synchronization too.