# How to communicate between two JVMs using memory-mapped files?

Tags: java, real-time, nio, memory-mapped-files

I was wondering how you would synchronize on a memory-mapped file to safely use it as a pipe between two JVMs. Has anyone done that before with success?

Comment: It might help desribing your use case as this seems to be a fairly uncommon requirement.

Comment: Why not just use a pipe and let the OS take care of it? Inter-JVM synchronisation is, I strongly suspect, inherently non-portable.

Comment: I think a similar (if not duplicate) [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491519/any-concept-of-shared-memory-in-java) was held here before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a library which does this but it doesn't use synchronization. It writes once to memory rather than reusing the memory which simplifies the memory model. [Java Chronicle](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle)

Comment: How does the consumer poll for new data in the memory-mapped file? What do you do when you eventually have to roll the memory-mapped file?

Comment: The consumer polls or busy waits.  I don't roll the memory mapped file. I assume there is enough disk space to last a day or a week and the application will be restarted to roll the files. Few applications need more than a couple of TB a day of data.