# Reading shared memory data using Java that is written by C++

Tags: java, c, ipc, shared-memory

I have an application in C/C++ that writes data in shared memory in Unix. Now I want to read that shared memory data through a program using Java.

The program should read the shared memory data. Can it be possible?

Need a small implementation if possible.

Comment: Reading shared memory does if ever only work through JNI - in Java you can't do that. My experience with JNI was that some JNI-plugins crashed the otherwise rock-solid Java VM. So maybe another solution is possible?

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1492536/1741542 talks about memory mapped files and NIO FileChannel. Maybe this works for you too.

Comment: If you would benefit from persistence of the data (even for debugging purposes) you could consider memory mapped files.  Here an implementation which uses pure Java https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle

Comment: @luukes
Are you sure that using a Java program we cannot read the shared memory data written by c++ program? And we have to have JNI in between to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2460/Using-Memory-Mapped-Files-and-JNI-to-communicate-b) codeproject project (For Windows):

> Using Memory Mapped Files and JNI to communicate between Java and C++
>   programs

Or, [this](http://www.downloadplex.com/Linux/Developer-Tools/Components-Libraries/clipc-for-linux_406179.html) library:

> CLIPC is an open-source Java library that gives developers
>   interprocess communications (IPC) capabilities that may be absent or
>   difficult to use in the Java distribution.

Comment: Can I create a method in C++ only to read the shared memory, and then call this method using JNI? Would that be effective and won't harm to performance also?

Comment: JNI methods should call from Java not C++. Yes you can create a method in C++ to read/write from/to the shared memory. And also you can do same thing in Java with JNI methods. Don't worry about performance if you do it right.

Comment: Can you please just tell me the suggestions how can I achieve the below functionality?