# How to have a common object across multiple JVMs

Tags: java, static, jvm, inter-process-communicat

There is an application that will need to have something like a look up table. This application can be started many times with different configurations. Is there a way to share a datastructure across JVMs. `static` would be valid within a JVM. Having a database would solve the issue. However, is there something simpler and fast?

Comment: http://terracotta.org/ is a product that solves some very similar tasks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any concept of shared memory in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491519/any-concept-of-shared-memory-in-java)

Comment: Some answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491519/any-concept-of-shared-memory-in-java and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396664/shared-memory-between-two-jvms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use a `file`. Write the object to a file. There is no such thing as *an object shared within JVMs* because the life cycle of an Object is defined *for and within a JVM*.

File IO is usually faster than DB operations and simpler as well. But on the downside, `ACID` properties are not guaranteed by files and there could be inconsistencies if multiple processes try to read / write on the same file.

Comment: Yes, it could be system pipes for example, using `RandomAccessFile`

Comment: @Andremoniy - Right :)