# Non-persistent mapped files in Java

Tags: java, c#, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files

C# offers non-persisted (memory-mapped) files and therefore shared memory that is not based on an actual file resulting in no disk I/O operations.

I would like to know how to do it in Java (beside writing C implementations or calling a C# dll.

I would like to do it under Linux (I would like not to use a ram drive).

Definition by Microsoft:

> Non-persisted files are memory-mapped files that are not associated with a file on a disk. When the last process has finished working with the file, the data is lost and the file is reclaimed by garbage collection. These files are suitable for creating shared memory for inter-process communications (IPC).

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491519/any-concept-of-shared-memory-in-java).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any concept of shared memory in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491519/any-concept-of-shared-memory-in-java)