# Support for non persisted memorymappedfile

Tags: java, c#, shared-memory, virtual-memory, memory-mapped-files

I want to implement memory mapped file concept as a shared memory to share data between two processes running in my windows system. One in Java and another in native (C# layer).

Both are running processes and hence i want to  use non persisted mechanism for memory mapped files instead of persisted file option (because a file poses a security threat ).

Java File Channels http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map(java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode, long, long) has an option to map to an existing file.

C# has option to map both a persisted file and a simple alias named map for non persisted file. Please check here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx

So i am looking as how i can create a mapping for non persisted mechanism in Java.

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: I would do a simple experiment and see if you can create a named global section in C# and access it in Java as a memory mapped file.

Comment: thanks for the reply...but my problem is how to access the map in Java...it seems java does not have any option to access the non persisted memory mapped file

Comment: I would try using the name you use for the section in C#. You're not creating a memory mapped file in C#, your creating  global section within the page file. C# may be able to recognize the name of the global section.

Comment: i got your point...let me check it once